# Difficulty getting data from Sqlite database between two days

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

I was doing an Android app that generates sales report for dates between the current date and seven days in the past. It worked fine, here's the code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-7);

String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

String sevenDayAgo = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

Cursor weeklyIncome = db.getResult("select sum(price) as total_income from sales where date between '"+sevenDayAgo+"' and '"+currentDate+"'");
Cursor weeklyCost = db.getResult("select sum(purchase_price * quantity) as total_cost from sales where date between '"+sevenDayAgo+"' and '"+currentDate+"'");
```

Say for example `currentDate = 31-08-2018` and `sevenDayAgo = 24-08-2018` this all worked fine but when I change my system date to the next day which is the next month and `currentDate` becomes `01-09-2018` the query doesn't return anything from the database, it should have returned records between `25-08-2018` and `01-09-2018` which has seven days in between. Somehow the query doesn't work when the 7 days are in two different months. I don't know what's going on and how to fix it.

p.s. The `date` column in sales table is of type `TEXT`.

Comment: You are mistaking by adding DAY_OF_YEAR; Instead you should use add with DATE, Below explained in details...

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. Also `LocalDate.toString` will give you for example `2018-09-01`, which can be sorted as strings, hence will solve your problem without any need for a formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the format you're using for dates (**dd-mm-yyyy**) isn't in lexicographic order. The string `'25-08-2018'` compares greater than `'01-09-2018'` . `x BETWEEN y AND z` is equivalent to `x >= y AND x <= z`. That condition won't be true for dates in that range using your format (Remember, they're just strings. sqlite does not have a [date type](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype).

You should be using ISO-8601 formats, like **yyyy-mm-dd**. These will sort properly (`'2018-08-25' < '2018-09-01'`) and will allow you to use the sqlite3 [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) on them.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose user has entered the birth date in 31/08/2018 this format :

Parse it like :

```
String[] parts = BirthField.getText().toString().trim().split("/");
int CAL_DAY, CAL_MONTH, CAL_YEAR;
if(parts.length == 3)
{
    CAL_DAY = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    CAL_MONTH = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    CAL_YEAR = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
}
```

You can check if user has entered a good date or not with :

```
if( CAL_DAY > 0 && CAL_DAY < 32 && CAL_MONTH > 0 && CAL_MONTH < 13 && CAL_YEAR > 1900 )
```

While storing in database table take below care :

```
Calendar CalendarEvent = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
CalendarEvent.set(Calendar.DATE, CAL_DAY);
CalendarEvent.set(Calendar.MONTH, CAL_MONTH - 1);
CalendarEvent.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(ScheduleTime) );
CalendarEvent.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
CalendarEvent.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.getDefault());
String DayConsidered = format.format(CalendarEvent.getTime());
```

Please note `CAL_MONTH - 1` as system starts months from 0 to 11

While storing store in database in `SystemTime` like :

```
SYSTIME = CalendarEvent.getTimeInMillis();
```

While using it again retrieve it from database and initialise calendar event with it like :

```
Calendar CalendarEvent = Calendar.getInstance();
CalendarEvent.setTimeInMillis( Long.parseLong(SYSTIME) );

int CAL_DAY = CalendarEvent.get(Calendar.DAY);
CalendarEvent.set(Calendar.DATE, CAL_DAY - 7);
```

And it will start working for even if days / months / even you change years from any date; it will always show the date which is less than 7 days

Hope it helps and let me know how it works as i am answering it quick...

> Edit : 2

Better and most efficient way which i am using in my project and working perfectly is :

```
Log.d("ADDING A MONTH :", "ADDING 1 MONTH....\n");
CalendarEvent.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

Log.d("NEGATING 7 DAYS :", "NEGATING 7 DAYS....\n");
CalendarEvent.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
```

Comment: thanks but i am not receiving any input from users.and i used dd-MM-yyyy format to store the date data in the database so i have to use the same format to retrieve it.don't u think? and i tried adding one to the month and changing from DAY_OF_YEAR to DATE like you said but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Yes it works... Update your code where you put data in database how you retrieve and how you negative 7 days .. full code of these 3 things

Comment: thanks for the help i was able to solve it by changing the formatting from `dd-MM-yyyy` to `yyyy-MM-dd` like Shawn suggested on the other answer